# Java Networking Framework

Tags: java, object-oriented, socket, server, client

So I've just written a framework that is supposed to make it easier to create a network-based application (client-server) using the native java.net package. I was wondering if the structure of my code is well understandable and if there are ways to improve my code (in both, readability and performance). I provided a UML-diagram to make it easier to gain a fast overview of the code I wrote:

[image]

And here is the source of the classes:

**AbstractClient.java**

```
package com.joshuafeld.net;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * A client can connect to a running server using native Java sockets. It can perform requests
 * and perform actions based on potential requests it can get from the server.
 */
public abstract class AbstractClient extends AbstractSocketWrapper {

    /**
     * Creates a new client with a socket that is connected to the specified port number on the
     * named host.
     *
     * <p>If the specified host is {@code null} it is the equivalent of specifying the address as
     * {@link java.net.InetAddress#getByName(String) InetAddress.getByName}{@code (null)}. In
     * other words, it is equivalent to specifying an address of the loopback interface.
     *
     * @param  address     The host name, or {@code null} for the loopback address.
     * @param  port        The port number.
     *
     * @throws IOException If an I/O error occurs when creating the underlying socket.
     */
    public AbstractClient(final String address, final int port) throws IOException {
        super(new Socket(address, port));
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    /**
     * This is just used to guarantee consistency in the client-server system. It calls the
     * method {@link #handleMessage(String) handleMessage} which then can be extended by a subclass.
     * This is created in the hope of making the system more understandable for a new user.
     *
     * @param message The message to handle.
     */
    @Override
    /* default */ void handle(final String message) {
        handleMessage(message);
    }

    /**
     * Handles an incoming message from the server.
     *
     * @param message The incoming message.
     */
    public abstract void handleMessage(String message);
}
```

**AbstractServer.java**

```
package com.joshuafeld.net;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A server that is based on the native Java sever socket implementation. A server waits for
 * requests to come in over the network. It performs some operation based on that request, and then
 * possibly returns a result to the requester.
 */
public abstract class AbstractServer {

    /**
     * Logs messages to the console.
     */
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractServer.class);

    /**
     * Waits for requests to come in over the network.
     */
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    /**
     * The currently open socket connections.
     */
    private final List<ConnectionSocket> sockets;

    /**
     * Creates a server with a server socket, bound to the specified port. A port number of
     * {@code 0} means that the port number is automatically allocated, typically from an ephemeral
     * port range. This port number can then be retrieved by calling {@link #getPort() getPort}.
     *
     * @param  port                     The port number, or {@code 0} to use a port number that is
     *                                  automatically allocated.
     *
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the port parameter is outside the specified range of
     *                                  valid port values which is between 0 and 65535, inclusive.
     */
    public AbstractServer(final int port) {
        if (port < 0 || port > 0xFFFF) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Port value out of range: " + port);
        }
        sockets = new LinkedList<>();
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (final IOException exception) {
            logger.error("An I/O error occurred while opening the server socket", exception);
        }
        new Thread(new ConnectionAcceptor()).start();
    }

    /**
     * Closes the server socket as well as all connected sockets.
     */
    public void close() {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (final IOException exception) {
            logger.error("An I/O error occurred while closing the server socket", exception);
        }
        sockets.forEach(this::close);
    }

    /**
     * Closes the specified socket and removes it from the list of currently connected sockets.
     *
     * @param socket The socket to close.
     */
    public void close(final ConnectionSocket socket) {
        handleDisconnect(socket);
        sockets.remove(socket);
        socket.close();
    }

    /**
     * Broadcasts a message to all connected sockets/clients.
     *
     * @param message The message to broadcast.
     */
    public void broadcast(final String message) {
        sockets.forEach(socket -> socket.send(message));
    }

    /**
     * Handles an incoming message from the specified socket.
     *
     * @param socket  The socket at which the message arrived.
     * @param message The message.
     */
    public abstract void handleMessage(ConnectionSocket socket, String message);

    /**
     * Handles a newly connected socket.
     *
     * @param socket The newly connected socket.
     */
    public abstract void handleConnect(ConnectionSocket socket);

    /**
     * Handles a disconnected/closed socket.
     *
     * @param socket The closed socket.
     */
    public abstract void handleDisconnect(ConnectionSocket socket);

    /**
     * Returns the IP address to which the server socket is bound.
     *
     * <p>If the server socket was bound prior to being {@link #close() closed}, then this method
     * will continue to return the IP address after the server socket is closed.
     *
     * @return The IP address to which the server socket is bound.
     */
    public String getAddress() {
        return serverSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the port number on which the server socket is listening.
     *
     * <p>If the server socket was bound prior to being {@link #close() closed}, then this method
     * will continue to return the port number after the server socket is closed.
     *
     * @return The port number on which the server socket is listening or -1 if the socket is not
     *         bound yet.
     */
    public int getPort() {
        return serverSocket.getLocalPort();
    }

    /**
     * Listens for a connection to be made to the server socket and accepts it.
     */
    private class ConnectionAcceptor implements Runnable {

        /**
         * Creates a new connection acceptor.
         */
        private ConnectionAcceptor() {
            // empty on purpose
        }

        /**
         * Listens for a connection to be made to the server socket and accepts it. The method
         * blocks until a connection is made or the server is {@link #close() closed}.
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!serverSocket.isClosed()) {
                try {
                    final ConnectionSocket socket = new ConnectionSocket(serverSocket.accept());
                    handleConnect(socket);
                    new Thread(socket).start();
                    sockets.add(socket);
                } catch (final IOException exception) {
                    logger.error("An I/O error occurred while waiting for a connection", exception);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The socket that represents the connection to a specific client.
     */
    public class ConnectionSocket extends AbstractSocketWrapper {

        /**
         * Creates a new wrapped socket. The socket has to be connected already.
         *
         * @param socket The socket to wrap.
         */
        public ConnectionSocket(final Socket socket) {
            super(socket);
        }

        /**
         * Passes the handling of the message on to the method
         * {@link #handleMessage(ConnectionSocket, String) handleMessage}.
         *
         * @param message The message to handle.
         */
        @Override
        void handle(final String message) {
            handleMessage(this, message);
        }
    }
}
```

**AbstractSocketWrapper.java**

```
package com.joshuafeld.net;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * A simple wrapper for the native Java {@link Socket Socket} that automatically handles messages
 * as soon as they are received by the underlying socket.
 */
public abstract class AbstractSocketWrapper implements Runnable {

    /**
     * Logs messages to the console.
     */
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractSocketWrapper.class);

    /**
     * The underlying socket/communication endpoint.
     */
    private final Socket socket;

    /**
     * Reads incoming messages from the input stream.
     */
    private BufferedReader input;
    /**
     * Writes messages to the output stream.
     */
    private PrintWriter output;

    /**
     * Creates a new wrapped socket. The socket has to be connected already.
     *
     * @param socket The socket to wrap.
     */
    public AbstractSocketWrapper(final Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (final IOException exception) {
            logger.error("An I/O error occurred while creating the input/output stream or the "
                    + "socket is not connected", exception);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Listens for new messages on the input stream and passes them on to the
     * {@link #handle(String) handle} method for further handling.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!socket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                input.lines().forEach(this::handle);
            } catch (final UncheckedIOException exception) {
                // This will happen if the input stream is closed. Because this is natural behavior
                // and not really an error, we will just ignore this and not log it into the
                // console.
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends a message to the connected socket. The message is terminated by a newline.
     *
     * @param message The message to send.
     */
    public void send(final String message) {
        if (!socket.isClosed()) {
            output.println(message);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes the socket as well as the input reader and output writer.
     *
     * <p>Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further networking use (i.e. can't
     * be reconnected or rebound). A new socket needs to be created.
     */
    public void close() {
        try {
            socket.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (final IOException exception) {
            logger.error("An I/O error occurred while closing the socket/input", exception);
        }
        output.close();
    }

    /**
     * Handles a received message.
     *
     * @param message The message to handle.
     */
    /* default */ abstract void handle(final String message);
}
```

---

Example of a simple daytime server/client using this code:

**DaytimeServer.java**

```
package com.joshuafeld.net.daytime;

import com.joshuafeld.net.AbstractServer;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DaytimeServer extends AbstractServer {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

    public DaytimeServer() {
        super(13);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleConnect(final ConnectionSocket socket) {
        socket.send(DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date()));
        socket.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final ConnectionSocket socket, final String message) {
        // nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    public void handleDisconnect(final ConnectionSocket socket) {
        // nothing to do here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DaytimeServer();
    }
}
```

**DaytimeClient.java**

```
package com.joshuafeld.net.daytime;

import com.joshuafeld.net.AbstractClient;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DaytimeClient extends AbstractClient {

    public DaytimeClient(String address) throws IOException {
        super(address, 13);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new DaytimeClient("localhost");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a working client/server example of this abstract API?

Comment: @dfhwze Yes I have added it to the question.

Comment: Accepting the first answer you get shortly after you get it tends to discourage further answers.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I'm new to this site so I wasn't quite sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I read through your profile and saw you are a 17 year old developer hobbiest. I didn't know what OO was at that age. Well done. I made this review under the impression you were a somewhat experienced professional.*

#### AbstractSocketWrapper

- The constructor silently catches `IOException`. This leaves the socket in a corrupted state. Throw any exception up the stack to let higher level classes decide how to handle the corrupted socket connection.
- method `run` could abort at any time when the the socket gets closed gracefully `!socket.isClosed()` or otherwise: `UncheckedIOException`. But the container class does not get notified about this. Perhaps you should raise an event. If not, container classes should periodically check for lingering socket connections and close them.
- method `send` prints a friendly message (with a new line). This suggests to me the API can only be used for human readable messages, which limits its usability. The guard in this method is also not that useful. A disconnected socket should get disposed correctly, and the guard does not guarantee that the call will succeed.
- method `close` seems robust, however when `socket.close();` fails, `input.close();` does not get called, possibly leading to unwanted behavior (memory leak?).

#### ConnectionAcceptor

- method `run` is ill-implemented. You perform `handleConnect(socket);` before `sockets.add(socket);`. And as you can see in your example server, a server can close the socket in `handleConnect`. This would mean a socket gets added even though it's already been closed.

#### AbstractServer

- method `close` is not robust. If any socket fails to close `sockets.forEach(this::close);` others will not get closed, causing lingering socket connections.
- method `broadcast` has the same issue that failure in unicasting to a single client prevents other clients from being sent to.

#### General

- Your API is not threadsafe. Consider using a locking mechanism when manipulating the list of connections in the server, and also when taking a snapshot of connections to send to.
- Your API should be made more robust against exceptions, and should check for lingering connections.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the detailed review. There is one thing I don't really understand: Why is it that if _"any socket fails to close sockets.forEach(this::close); others will not get closed, causing lingering socket connections"_? Shouldn't the for-each loop just continue and close the next one since no exception is thrown if closing a socket fails?

Comment: _output.close()_ might still throw an exception. And I suggested in my review that _close_ on _AbstractSocketWrapper_ should throw exceptions, so the server can handle them appropriately. It's my opinion that container classes should handle exceptions of classes they use (in most cases).

Comment: Ah alright I understand, thanks again!